org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException on @Pattern()
I'm programming a web site backend but I having a problem with annotation @Pattern(). In this code I have a compcomponent and it should have a 2 digit value
This is my DTO:
package med.absolut.api.endereco;

import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Pattern;

public record DadosEndereco(

        @NotBlank
        String logradouro,

        @NotBlank
        String bairro,

        @NotBlank
        @Pattern(regexp = "\\d{8}")
        String cep,

        @NotBlank
        String cidade,

        @NotBlank 
        @Pattern(regexp = "\\d{2}") 
        String uf,

        String numero,
        String complemento){

}

but the console exit is an org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException.
This is the Json on the Insomnia
{   
    "nome": "Jorge Macedo",
    "email": "jorge.macedo@absolut.med",
    "crm": "122345",
    "telefone": "41992234444",
    "especialidade": "NEUROLOGIA",  
    "endereco": {
    "logradouro": "rua 2",
    "bairro": "Agua verda",
    "cep": "12345678",
    "cidade": "Curitiba",
    "uf": "PR",
    "numero": "1",
    "complemento": "complemento"
    }
}


You say that uf should be two digits (and that is what the pattern also requires), but the actual value for uf is "PR", which is two letters instead of two digits.

But I need the uf to be 2 digits, how do I do it?

I don't know where the value of uf is created. Is it from some incoming request? Then you must change the source of that request. If it is stored like this in your database then the data in your database is wrong.

The uf is sent by the user when registering, in the database is really simple the collum uf it's only NotNull varchar(2)

If it is sent by the user and the user should send two digits but sends two letters then the user sends invalid data - and spring rightfully rejects it.

It does exactly what you told it to. It will only accepts numbers (that is what \\d means). So it accepts 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 (and allows that to repeat twice). Your user is sending PR which isn't a digit but a character/letter. Hence the validation rejects it because that is what it is told to do. So either you don't mean digits but rather any character from the alphabet or the input provided by the user is indeed wrong.

The issue is related to the validation constraints set on the uf field in your DadosEndereco record. The @Pattern(regexp = "\d{2}") annotation specifies that the uf field should be exactly two digits. However, based on the JSON provided, uf is supposed to be a two-letter state abbreviation, like "PR".
You should update the regular expression in the @Pattern annotation for uf to match two uppercase letters instead of two digits.
The correct regular expression for two uppercase letters is ^[A-Z]{2}$.
public class DadosEndereco{

    @NotBlank 
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[A-Z]{2}$") 
    String uf,

    ...
}


In case you accept uf as 2 letters (CAPITALS) or 2 digits use this pattern:
@Pattern(regexp = "^[A-Z]{2}$|^[0-9]{2}$")

Of course you may use \d instead of [0-9].
If you accept any 2 letters, CAPITALS and non-capitals or 2 digits use this pattern:
@Pattern(regexp = "^[A-Za-z]{2}$|^[0-9]{2}$")

